# Change button text value from dropdown list on click event VueJS with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js

I have button it has click event which opens the dropdown list. What i want when user select option from the list it should update the button text and remove from the dropdown list according to the user Selection. 
When i'm using {{interestSortingOptions.label}} it is empty nothing is showing.

This is my code

```
<button
    @click="interested = !interested"
>
   {{interestSortingOptions.label}}
   <sort-options
     v-if="interested && interestSortingOptions.length"
     :options="interestSortingOptions"
     />
</button>

export default class DetailFollow extends Vue {
    private interested: boolean = false

    private interestSortingOptions: SortingOption[] = [{
            label: 'Interested',
            value: 'interested',
        },
        {
            label: 'Scenario',
            value: 'scenario',
        },
        {
            label: 'Screening',
            value: 'screening',
        },
        {
            label: 'Offer',
            value: 'offer',
        }]

}
```

Can anyone help me with this how can i get this done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So from what I can see, your button is the list as well as the button? If you use the `<select>` element for the list, then you can attach a function to the `onchange()` event for the `<select>` element which could remove the selected item.

Comment: Also: You have `interested: boolean = false` twice in your declaration. And `{{interestSortingOptions.label}}` wouldn't work because `interestSortingOptions` is an array of Objects. You'd have to use `{{interestSortingOptions[0].label}}` for it to work (with the index coming from a loop or hardcoded).

Comment: button is not a list. Yes i can use the <select> but then i will have some styling issues. Is it not possible to update the button text from dropdown list onclick event?

Comment: Which dropdown list? If you have no <select> element, how do you select which to add/remove?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a pen for you which I believe does what you want but uses a `<select>` element instead of a button: https://codepen.io/xon5/pen/ewWqEa
Even if it doesn't, I think you will find the methods there.

Template:

```
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedOption" @change="showInterest">
    <option v-for="iOption in interestSortingOptions" :key="iOption.value" :value="iOption.value">{{iOption.label}}</option>
  </select>
  <p>Selected: {{interestsSelected.join(', ')}}</p>
</div>
```

Vue Object:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      selectedOption: null,
      interestsSelected: [],
      interestSortingOptions: [
        {
          label: "Interested",
          value: "interested"
        },
        {
          label: "Scenario",
          value: "scenario"
        },
        {
          label: "Screening",
          value: "screening"
        },
        {
          label: "Offer",
          value: "offer"
        }
      ],
    interested: false
  };
},
methods: {
  showInterest() {
    this.interestsSelected.push(this.selectedOption);
    this.interestSortingOptions = this.interestSortingOptions.filter(v => {
      return v.value !== this.selectedOption;
    });
    this.selectedOption = null;
  }
}
});
```